# String Encoding doesn't ouput all characters

Tags: java, android, html, encoding

My client uses InputStreamReader/BufferedReader to fetch text from the Internet.
However when I save the Text to a *.txt the text shows extra weird special symbols like 'Â'.

- I've tried Convert the String to ASCII but that mess upp å,ä,ö,Ø which I use.
- I've tried food = `food.replace("Â", ""); and IndexOf();`
  But string won't find it. But it's there in HEX Editor.

So summary: When I use `text.setText`(Android), the output looks fine with NO weird symbols, but when I save the text to *.txt I get about 4 of 'Â'. I do not want ASCII because I use other Non-ASCII character.
The 'Â' is displayed as a Whitespace on my Android and in notepad.

Thanks!

Have A great Weekend!

EDIT:
Solved it by removing all Non-breaking-spaces:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\u00a0"," ");
```

Comment: Add the code you use to save the value to a file.

Comment: I use a FileWriter, but it doesnt matter becuase if I use mString.replace(" ", ""); which should remove all spaces. But Android still show a whitespace where  'Â' is in HEX Editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are fetching like this:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8"));
```

There is a fair chance that the stuff you are fetching is not encoded in UTF-8.

You need to call `getContentType()` on the HttpURLConnection object, and if it is non-null, extract the encoding and use it when you create the `InputStreamReader`.  Only assume "UTF-8" if the response doesn't supply a content type with a valid encoding.

---

On reflection, while you SHOULD pay attention to the content type returned by the server, the real problem is either in the way that you are writing the *.txt file, or in the display tool that is showing strange characters.

- It is not clear what encoding you are using to write the file.  Perhaps you have chosen the wrong one.
- It is possible that the display tool is assuming that the file has a different encoding.  Maybe it detects that a file is UTF-8 or UTF-16 is there is a BOM.
- It is possible that the display tool is plain broken, and doesn't understand non-breaking spaces.

When you display files using a HEX editor, it is most likely using an 8-bit character set to render bytes, and that character set is most likely Latin-1.  But apparently, the file is actually encoded differently.

Anyway, the approach of replacing non-breaking spaces is (IMO) a hack, and it won't deal with other stuff that you might encounter in the future.  So I recommend that you take the time to really understand the problem, and fix it properly.

---

Finally, I think I understand why you might be getting Â characters.  A Unicode NON-BREAKING-SPACE character is `u00a0`.  When you encode that as UTF-8, you get C2 A0.  But C2 in Latin-1 is CAPITAL-A-CIRCUMFLEX, and A0 in Latin-1 is NON-BREAKING-SPACE.  So the "confusion" is most likely that your program is writing the *.txt file in UTF-8 and the tool is reading it as Latin-1.

Comment: HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="sv" lang="sv">

<head profile="http://dublincore.org/documents/dcq-html/">

 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 " />

Comment: Even so, you should respect the response header.  What contentType is it returning?

Comment: I am using utf-8. What do you mean?

Comment: What Stephen C is implying, is that the HTTP Response Header might be *different* from what is specified in the html metatag, and "overrules" it as far as the incoming characterst is concerned. See http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php.